# "Some text layers contain fonts that are missing" when opening PSD files in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am browsing sample brochure templates at this [website](http://blogsizzle.com/templates/brochure-templates-free-psd-download/). The templates are available in PSD format.

To open PSD files, I downloaded a trial version of Photoshop CS6. But whenever I double-click a PSD file, I get the following message:

Some text layers contain fonts that are missing. These layers will need to have the missing fonts replaced before they can be used for vector based output.

I am new to Photoshop; does this message mean that the available PSD file has some issue or am I not opening the files the right way ? I need to edit these templates as-is using the fonts shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that your operating system does not have the fonts installed that were used in making those PSD files. This means that if you try and edit the text in those files, Photoshop will use the Myriad font to render the text and this will change the appearance of the file from its original look. The only solution is to make sure you have the same fonts installed or to render the type layers as pixel layers. Read through Photoshop's help files to learn more about this.

Comment: Thanks .. I got over the hurdle .. could you also tell once a PSD file is finalized, how to render the final image ? any link would be helpful !

Comment: What do you mean by rendering? Like saving out a different file format? Use the "Save As" and "Save For Web" functions under the "File" menu.

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues with the .PSD files. All you need to do is:

1. You need to download those fonts and install them in your computer. You can download the fonts and the open the .PSD file.
2. Replace the fonts with the fonts available in your computer.

You can download fonts available for free in

- [1001 Free Fonts](https://www.1001freefonts.com/)
- [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/)
- [FontSpace](https://www.fontspace.com/)

After downloading them click install.